# Adding cropper function to dynamically created image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input with url, and 'preview' button.
When I click 'preview' it inserts image from this url, before 'submit' button.

```
  $('#preview').click(function() {
    var image_url = $('#event_remote_flyer_url').val();
    var image_tag = $('<img class="preview">');
    image_tag.attr('src',image_url)
    $('input[name="commit"]').before(image_tag);
  });
```

Now I want to add cropper plugin for this image. (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

Docs say I should use it like this:

```
$('img.preview').cropper({
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop: function(e) {
    // Output the result data for cropping image.
    console.log(e.x);
    console.log(e.y);
    console.log(e.width);
    console.log(e.height);
    console.log(e.rotate);
    console.log(e.scaleX);
    console.log(e.scaleY);
  }
});
```

It doesn't work. As I understand javascript is not waiting with this cropper function and runs it when `img.preview` is not inserted yet. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach it when creating `img.preview` elements and your understanding is spot on.

```
$('#preview').click(function() {
    var image_url = $('#event_remote_flyer_url').val();
    var image_tag = $('<img class="preview">');
    image_tag.attr('src', image_url)
        //Atach Cropper
    image_tag.cropper({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        crop: function(e) {}
    });
    //Append
    $('input[name="commit"]').before(image_tag);
});
```

Comment: Now I see the cropper grid, but image is not uploaded.

Comment: And get this error: `Image from origin 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`